# oozie coordinator input-event does not work

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins, oozie-coordinator

I have three coordinators A, B and C.

The coordinator of B and C depends on the output of A. That is, if the output of A is ready, coordinator of B and C will run.

So, I use an input-event to control such dependency.

The structure of coordinator B and C look like

```
<coordinator-app name="B" frequency="1440" start=${start} end=${end} timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <datasets>
      <dataset name="input1" frequency="1440" initial-instance=${start} timezone="UTC">
         <uri-template>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
      </dataset>
   </datasets>
   <input-events>
      <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
          <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
      </data-in>
   </input-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/B/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>     
</coordinator-app>
```

So, if `hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/_SUCCESS` is created, the coordinator B and C will be triggered to run their workflow.

the coordinator of A looks like:

```
<coordinator-app name="B" frequency="1440" start=${start} end=${end} timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/A/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

its `${start}` and `${end}` are same as B and C.

The workflow of A will create `hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/_SUCCESS`

However, the coordinator of B and C are still waiting for the `hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/_SUCCESS`

Even though I use output event of coordinator of A, the workflow of B and C are still wanting for the created input dataset.

```
<coordinator-app name="A" frequency="1440" start=${start} end=${end} timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
    <datasets>
        <dataset name="output1" frequency="1440" initial-instance=${start} timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>

    <output-events>
        <data-out name="coordOutput1" dataset="output1">
            <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-out>
    </output-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/A/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

However, if I submit the workflow of A without its coordinator, then the workflow of B and C will be triggered as expected.

I am not sure if something missing in my coordinator of A.

Thank you!

Comment: **Q1.** In your code sample, Coordinator A is named "B". Is that a copy/paste typo? **Q2.** Why don't you just trigger 2 sub-workflows in parallel (*B* and *C*) when *A* has completed - because *A* may want to restart before *B* and/or *C* are done?

Comment: yes! it's a typo. Is it possible to trigger workflows directly from one workflow and run each of them in parallel ( B and C are run in parallel) with oozie? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at "Fork/Join" Actions and "Sub-Workflows" Actions. For example in that old but comprehensive tutorial: http://www.infoq.com/articles/oozieexample *-- then tag my comment as useful if it was :-)*

Comment: Thanks. I will try it in the next two days. Anyway, I still do not understand why my approach did not work and it will work if I submit the workflow of A without its coordinator. I think the coordinator of B and C will always monitor the directory ```hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}``` and they will be triggered if the directory is ready.

Comment: Disclaimer: I feel lucky never to have had to mess with these "datasets"...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you did not specified the done-flag, so oozie uses the default: _success

> done-flag: The done file for the data set. If done-flag is not
>   specified, then Oozie configures Hadoop to create a _SUCCESS file in
>   the output directory. If the done flag is set to empty, then
>   Coordinator looks for the existence of the directory itself.

You should add an empty

```
<done-flag></done-flag>
```

to the dataset.

Comment: In fact, the workflow of A created _success file in its output directory but the other dependent workflows did not run.

Comment: Ohh I see and you also mentined it... Really strange. Let me replicate your issue.